# Json parse error on what looks to be good string (Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BOOLEAN)

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

So, we're working in java, the object being deserialized is structured as so

```
@ApiModel(description = "Container for collection of Patient Search results")
public class PatientSearchResultListCMRefactor {

private final List<PatientSearchResultCMRefactor> patientSearchResults;
private final int totalSearchResults;
//getters, toString, etc
}
```

The object referenced in that object is as follows

```
public final class PatientSearchResultCMRefactor {

private float score;

private String id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String setupDate;

private Optional<AddressCM> address;
private Optional<Boolean> active;
private Optional<String> dateOfBirth;
private Optional<String> email;
private Optional<String> patientExternalId;
private Optional<String> patientReference;
private Optional<String> phoneNumber;
private Optional<String> currentAverageDaysUsed;
private Optional<Double> currentAverageHoursUsed;

private Optional<PatientOrganizationCM> organization;
private Optional<PatientOrganizationCM> topOrganization;

private Optional<ImmutableSet<PatientClinicianCM>> clinicians;

private Optional<ImmutableSet<PatientLocationCMRefactor>> locations;

private Optional<ImmutableSet<PatientDeviceCM>> devices;

private Optional<String> matchesBy;
//setters, getters, left-handed smoke-shifters, constructors
```

}

the code to deserialize it is

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println(response.getBody());
String jsonTemp = response.getBody();
System.out.println(jsonTemp);
PatientSearchResultListCMRefactor resultListCM = gson.fromJson(jsonTemp, PatientSearchResultListCMRefactor.class);
```

The full string being deserialized is

```
{
  "patientSearchResults": [
    {
      "score": 0.7582117,
      "id": "3910dc3d-913b-4862-aee5-4610d2c2981f",
      "firstName": "Nelda",
      "lastName": "Dixon 36",
      "setupDate": "2018-07-19",
      "address": {
        "streetAddress": "0545 Route 202",
        "city": "Joliet",
        "stateProvince": "SC",
        "zipCode": "87636",
        "countryCode": "USA"
      },
      "active": true,
      "dateOfBirth": "1971-01-16",
      "email": "n_dixon_RRAwyqXKIp@example.com",
      "patientExternalId": "6bc63dfa-1106-40c9-875a-a74368cf5189",
      "patientReference": null,
      "phoneNumber": "365-177-2753",
      "currentAverageDaysUsed": null,
      "currentAverageHoursUsed": null,
      "organization": null,
      "topOrganization": null,
      "clinicians": [

      ],
      "locations": null,
      "devices": [

      ],
      "matchesBy": null
    }
],
  "totalSearchResults": 17
}
```

The error is

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 289
```

which is right after

```
"address": {
    "streetAddress": "0545 Route 202",
    "city": "Joliet",
    "stateProvince": "SC",
    "zipCode": "87636",
    "countryCode": "USA"
  },
  "active": true,
```

in the string, with the comma after "true" being column 289 (for clarification, line and column numbers are from before I prettyprinted the string). I think it's expecting a new object, but address is a sub-object nested in the top object, and sub-objects never go more than 1 level deep, though per the PatientSearchResultCMRefactor model there are multiple sub-objects. I'm a tester, and this is the body of a ReST API call, so I can't really change the format of the response. All I can do is try to parse it as-is. Any tips?

Comment: `"patientSearchResults": [` <= That array does not close anywhere.

Comment: @dhke you're right, thank you. Unfortunately, that was just a transcription error, which I've corrected.

Comment: Have you checked that `AddressCM` is correctly defined?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yeah, I checked all of the objects referenced in PatientSearchResultCMRefactor for correctness. All the variables are accounted for, with appropriate setters and getters.

Comment: only one thing I can think about: is `setActive` parameter defined as `boolean` or as `java.lang.Boolean`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: It turns out, gson has real trouble with optional variables and immutable sets. Once I changed PatientResultCMRefactor to

```
public final class PatientSearchResultCMRefactor {

private float score;

private String id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String setupDate;

private AddressCM address;
private Boolean active;
private String dateOfBirth;
private String email;
private String patientExternalId;
private String patientReference;
private String phoneNumber;
private String currentAverageDaysUsed;
private Double currentAverageHoursUsed;

private PatientOrganizationCM organization;
private PatientOrganizationCM topOrganization;

private Set<PatientClinicianCM> clinicians;

private Set<PatientLocationCMRefactor> locations;

private Set<PatientDeviceCM> devices;

private String matchesBy;
//getters, setters, etceterrers
}
```

Everything deserializes perfectly. Posting this as an answer rather than updating the question to make it easier for others to find in the future.